# What is the official name for this syntax feature?

Tags: vb.net, syntax, language-features

What is the name of the character at the end of each of these lines?

```
Dim _int As Integer = 1I
Dim _short As Short = 1S
Dim _long As Long = 1L
Dim _single As Single = 1.0F
Dim _double As Decimal = 1D
```

I've always called these "type specifiers". I assume that's incorrect as I'm unable to find the official documentation using this term. I would like to know what others are available but can't find the right term to use in my search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek) in VB.NET they are called "literal type characters". See the section on "forced literal types".

Answer (score 5):

It's called a type suffix.

Comment: Thanks @Jon, was looking for it but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfft1t3c.aspx) in ***C#*** are called: **`Type suffix`**